# Перегрузка оператор []

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Мне нужно перегрузить оператор [] в моём классе который бы вернул ссылку на 1 элемент вектора типа char. Чтобы я мог написать следующее:

```
    class myclass;
    myclass[0] = 'f';
```

Важно: Оператор должен вернуть именно ссылку, а не просто тип char.

Что я пытался сделать:

```
   char* operator[](size_t INDEX_)
   {
      if (INDEX_ + 1 > DATA.size())
      {
          throw MYSTR_OUT_RANGE;
      }
      return &DATA[INDEX_]; //Это возвращает ссылку на внутренний буфер вектора, а мне нужен элемент
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
char& operator[](size_t INDEX_)
{
    if (INDEX_ + 1 > DATA.size())
    {
         throw MYSTR_OUT_RANGE;
    }
    return DATA[INDEX_];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Harry, не смог удержаться... Рад видеть вас здесь в эти трудные времена...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Спасибо на добром слове. Поскольку от моего дома до полосы в Гостомеле около 10 км, а с отоплением в квартире проблемы... пришлось переехать на другой конец Киева к друзьям. Сегодня смог наконец съездить забрать компьютер, уж слишком скучал... Надеюсь хоть иногда появляться — пока есть такая возможность как технически, так и, главное, биологически :) Мой академический институт уже свое получил, стоит без окон...

Comment: @Harry, а уехать в сторону запада ради безопасности не  лучше вариант?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan В этой войне бомбят везде. Мне только 59, из страны я выехать не могу (да и не поехал бы), да и в стране у меня родственники есть только на юге, где точно так же... мы решили — будь что будет, но мы останемся вместе, семьей до последнего, и не побежим никуда.

Comment: @Harry,  тогда дай Бог вам выдержать  без потерь.  Не место для обсуждения такого рода,  но мы с вами  почти ровесники,  служили одной Родине может в один призыв, и вот что творится... Грустно и обидно